# Label do materialize não sobe quando populo um input

Tags: materialize, angular-material

Quando  busco os dados para preencher os inputs a label não sobe, ficando em cima do valor do input segue imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 ">
        <h4>Cadastrar Cliente</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="" name="formulario">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                <input id="inputNome" type="text" class="validate" name="Nome" ng-model="cliente.nome" value="{{cliente.Nome}}">
                <label for="inputNome">Nome</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
                <input id="inputCPF" type="text" class="validate" name="CPF" ng-model="cliente.cpf" value="{{cliente.Cpf}}">
                <label for="inputCPF">CPF</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
                <input id="inpuEmail" type="email" class="validate" name="Email" ng-model="cliente.email" value="{{cliente.Email}}">
                <label for="inpuEmail">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                <input id="inputResidencial" type="tel" class="validate" name="Residencial" ng-model="cliente.telefone.residencial" value="{{cliente.Telefone.Residencial}}">
                <label for="inputResidencial">Residêncial</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                <input id="inputCelular" type="tel" class="validate" name="Celular" ng-model="cliente.telefone.celular" value="{{cliente.Telefone.Celular}}">
                <label for="inputCelular">Celular</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                <input id="inputComercial" type="tel" class="validate" name="Comercial" ng-model="cliente.telefone.comercial" value="{{cliente.Telefone.Comercial}}">
                <label for="inputComercial">Comercial</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                <input id="inputCEP" type="text" class="validate" name="Cep" ng-model="cliente.endereco.cep" value="{{cliente.Endereco.Cep}}" ng-blur=" buscaEnderecoPorCep(cliente.endereco.cep)">
                <label for="inputCEP">CEP</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                <input id="inputNumero" type="text" class="validate" name="Numero" ng-model="cliente.Endereco.Numero">
                <label for="inputNumero">Número</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                <input id="inputLogradouro" type="text" class="validate" name="Logradouro" ng-model="cliente.endereco.logradouro" value="{{cliente.Endereco.Logradouro}}">
                <label for="inputLogradouro">Logradouro</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                <input id="inputBairro" type="text" class="validate" name="Bairro" ng-model="cliente.endereco.bairro" value="{{cliente.Endereco.Bairro}}">
                <label for="inputBairro">Bairro</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                <input id="inputLocalidade" type="text" class="validate" name="Localidade" ng-model="cliente.endereco.localidade" value="{{cliente.Endereco.Localidade}}">
                <label for="inputLocalidade">Localidade</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s5 m5 l5">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">location_city</i>
                <input id="inputEstado" type="text" class="validate" name="Estado" ng-model="cliente.endereco.uf" value="{{cliente.Endereco.UF}}">
                <label for="inputEstado">Estado</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row left-align">
            <div class="col s5 m5 l5">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" ng-click="submeter()" name="action">
                    Submit
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: eh um bug que já havia sido corrigido no projeto, mas foi sobre escrito. Tu podes adicionar manualmente a classe como na resposta abaixo, como esta como ma das Issues no repositório do projeto creio que logo sera corrigido.

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272038/materialize-css-label-fixo-no-topo/272057#272057, mas basicamente é setar a classe `class="active"` na label quando vc carregar os dados

Answer (score 1):

Simples, basta adicionar a *class="active"* no label, e chamar a função **Materialize.updateTextFields();**

Exemplo:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <input value="John Leno" id="meuinput" type="text" class="validate">
  <label class="active" for="meuinput">Meu Nome</label>
</div>
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Materialize.updateTextFields();
  });
```

PS. Copie e cole na sua página para testar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma saída é colocar um ngClass no label como o exemplo abaixo

```
<label for="name" [ngClass]="{'active': user.name }">Name</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para atualizar chame o método Materialize.updateTextFields(); após atualizar os valores, porém chame dentro de um setTimeout(() => {}, 0) para garantir que chamou a update após os valores estarem atualizados.

Ex.:

```
import * as M from 'materialize-css';

setCliente(cliente: Cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
    setTimeout(() => { M.updateTextFields() }, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona esse javascript na página, ele faz com que o `Materialize` atualize as caixas de input, caso precise de mais informações segue o link da documentação oficial.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   M.updateTextFields();
});
```

https://materializecss.com/text-inputs