# Materialize CSS - label fixo no topo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, materialize

Como faço pra fixar meu label sempre no Topo?

Comportamento normal: fica no `input`, quando clicamos no `input` (focus) ele fica em cima do `input`

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta, colocando trecho do que você já tem desenvolvido? assim fica mais fácil para te ajudarmos.

Comment: Não há necessidade, mais colocarei um trecho qualquer encontrado no mesmo site do Materialize css. é que é algo que quem conheçe a ferramente, sabe do que falo

Comment: Exatamente
quem conhece a ferramenta ou seja seu materialize especifico
coloque pelo menos o link para ele para podermos ver quais classes ele usa
pois provavelmente exite uma classe que define isso na propria ferramenta

Comment: Sempre quando? Aparentemente ele já está no topo, mesmo quando o `input` está vazio... Ele só tem um efeito quando aperta F5 que é fazer o `label` subir para antes do `input`, é esse efeito que vc quer remover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Versão 1.0.0** *(mais recente)*

Na versão mais atual do Materialize para deixar a `label` no topo basta adicionar nela a classe `active`, por exemplo `<label class="active" for="first_name">Label Active</label>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro detalhe **importante** é que para a `label` ficar no topo, o `input` que vem antes dela deve estar com o *placeholder* vazio, então no `input` que antecede essa `label` vc tem que deixar a propriedade vazia `placeholder=""`. Isso acontece pq automaticamente quando vc usa `placeholder` no `input` a `label` relacionada já fica no topo.

Seque código da imagem acima.

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
 <form class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input placeholder="" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label class="active" for="first_name">Label Active</label>
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="first_name2" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name2">Labem padão</label>
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input placeholder="texto do placeholder" id="first_name2" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name2">Labem padão</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

---

> **Versão 0.100.2** *(versão antiga)*

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, se vc quer o Label do `input` sempre no topo sem a animação vc tem que colocar no `.input-field label` os mesmo valores do `.input-field label:not(.label-icon).active`

```
.input-field label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-14px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(-14px) scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

**Execute o Snippet e veja o exemplo funcionando com o Label sempre no topo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
.input-field label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-14px) scale(0.8);
    transform: translateY(-14px) scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input value="" id="first_name2" type="text" class="validate">
      <label class="fixed" for="first_name2">First Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Luiz Felipe, esse exemplo foi tirado do *showCase* do **MaterializeCSS**:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
</div>
```

- Na primeira `div` o `label` fica fixo na parte de cima e o `placeHolder` fica dentro do `input`
- Na segunda `div` o `label` fica dentro do `input` e sobe para cima do `input` quando foca

A sua pergunta está um pouco confusa pois o código que você postou deverá ter o comportamento esperado. Você não está confundindo algo da pergunta? O código ou o comportamento esperado?

---

#### Referência:

http://materializecss.com/forms.html