# Como forçar estado de elemento do template HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angular

Utilizando o framework CSS [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/), me deparei com a seguinte situação. Possuo alguns campos `<input>` com `<label>` como o exemplo:

```
<label for="name">Nome</label>
<input type="text"
       formControlName="name"
       id="name"/>
```

O que gera esse resultado:

[image: Campo com o label ocupando a área de texto como padrão]

Então eu alterei o elemento `<label>` adicionando a classe `.active`, como mostrado na [documentação](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html):

```
<label for="name" class="active">Nome</label>
<input type="text"
       formControlName="name"
       id="name"/>
```

O que gera o resultado desejado:

[image: campo modificado para o resultado desejado]
[image: exemplo do resultado desejado]

Porém, se eu seleciono o campo vazio e clico fora dele sem escrever nada ele volta ao estado original. Como eu posso forçar o campo ao estado "ativo" (forçar o comportamento da página para como se o campo estivesse preenchido)?

Comment: Cara seu código está igual nas duas referencias ai da sua pergunta, não deveria ter uma Classe? Outra coisa, da uma olhada nisso, veja se resolve, acredito que o campo deva ter que ter um placeholder como na última imagem... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272038/materialize-css-label-fixo-no-topo/272057#272057

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado, acrescentei a classe. Sobre o link, resolveu meu problema. Mas existe uma forma de forçar o estado de um componente da forma que eu descrevi?

Comment: Coloca um placeholder vazio no input: `<input placeholder ...>`

Comment: Sim, no blur vc volta a classe tipo `<input type="text" onblur="this.classList.add('ativo');">` tem que ver se isso vai ter mais força que o JS que remove a classe, se não der certo coloca em um js separado e indexa depois do js do Materialize. Talvez com o placeholder vazio como o @sam falou tb resolva...

Comment: Eu não testei mas de repente pode ajudar. Supondo que você tenha um `FormGroup` com o nome `meuFormGroup`, você poderia utilizar a propriedade `touched` do `FormControl` `nome` para injetar a classe CSS: `<input [ngClass]="{ active: meuFormGrou.controls.name.touched }" type="text" formControlName="name" id="name" />`. O `touched` só vai ser `true` quando o evento `onBlur` for disparado no componente.